# Bidi support for Arabic when installing from source?

Tags: install, bidirectional-support

**Q:** how can I get get full bidi support for Arabic when
installing Emacs from source?

I compiled Emacs from source (v. 26.1) and found that
the bidi is not working correctly for Arabic.

The good: I can input Arabic characters in right-to-left form
(correct).

The bad: none of the letters connect (Arabic is a scripted language, and the letters are supposed to connect).  So, for example, the following phrase:

```
بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم
```

gets rendered in Emacs (via `emacs -Q`) as:

[image: Emacs Arabic display]

I was previously using Emacs v. 25, installed via my distro's
package manager.  I am using the same font as before, which has
good support for Arabic characters.

How can I get full bidi support when installing via source?

Comment: You could look at build scripts used to build the package, you're probably missing a switch in your `configure` invocation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that your Emacs is built with support for text shaping.  AFAIK, it's the `--with-m17n-flt` option to configure.  This option is activated automatically but only if the relevant include files are found.

On Debian-derived systems a good way to make sure you have all the relevant packages installed is to use something like:

```
apt-get build-dep emacs
```